# X11: how do I get the font I want?

Tags: fonts, x11, xlib

My program wants to load a monospace font with this command:

```
font_info = XLoadQueryFont(dpy,
        "-*-*-medium-r-*-*-12-*-*-*-m-*-iso8859-1");
```

The font it ends up loading is

```
-apple-monaco-medium-r-normal--12-87-100-100-m-90-iso8859-1
```

How can I get my local machine to realize that the "best" font to use is

```
-urw-nimbus mono l-medium-r-normal--12-87-100-100-m-90-iso8859-1
```

I don't want to name a specific font in my program, because I can't guarantee that my computer will have it.  I want my computer to know that this is the best font to use.

Is this possible?

Comment: you haven't defined a criteria for 'best'. the apple font is the first in alphabetical order that satisfies. why don't you embed your fonts with the app and specifically call thoss fonts. otherwise you're going to need a switch/case statement that falls through if not found.

Comment: The criteria is pretty much "whatever my favorite is."  My goal is to learn how to define the criteria for "best" and tell my local computer "When you have to pick a font, pick them in this order".  My programming skills aren't good enough to embed fonts, and I was just hoping that the program would be able to pick a font.

Comment: The apple font is not the first one alphabetically.  I also have -adobe-courier-medium-r-normal

Comment: then write a  big case statement.

Comment: So you're saying there is no way for my computer to prioritize fonts between each other?  It's going to pick whatever font it wants that satisfies my criteria, and I can't adjust the order?

Comment: you prioritize the order with the wildcards. you can use partial matches and it will pseudo pick the best one the matches.  i think there is a rudimentary algorithm and it scans system fonts then user fonts.  of course apple being a megalomanic company likes its own font preferences first.

Comment: You cannot teach `XLoadQueryFont` to ask for the best font. It was never intended to work this way. It returns the first font it finds. Most modern X11 programs handle fonts client-side and this method allows you to prioritize fonts.

Answer (score 0):

Create your own priority list and you can leave that as a fallback. Try loading *nimbus* font first.

```
font_info = XLoadQueryFont(dpy,
                           "-*-nimbus*-medium-r-*-*-12-*-*-*-m-*-iso8859-1");
if (!font_info) {
    fprintf(stderr, "XLoadQueryFont: failed to load nimbus font, looking for a fallback font\n");
    font_info = XLoadQueryFont(dpy,
                               "-*-*-medium-r-*-*-12-*-*-*-m-*-iso8859-1");
}
if (!font_info)
    fprintf(stderr, "XLoadQueryFont: failed to load a font\n");
```

Comment: The intent was ... for the program to ask for `-*-*-medium-r-*-*-12-*-*-*-m-*-iso8859-1` , and for the individual client to answer "i will try nimbus first" or "i will try console first" or "i will try lucida first".  I didn't want to put a specific font in the program itself if I could avoid it.